# How to rearrange Action's execution in a Test in UFT?

Tags: testing, automation, action, qtp

I am facing a problem while executing **multiple Actions** in a **single Test** in *UFT*. I have 3 Actions namely **Action1**, **Action2** and **Action3** and I need to run *Action3* first then *Action1* and lastly the *Action2*. But the problem is when I execute my test *UFT* always runs the *Action1* first then *Action2* and lastly *Action3*.

So, is there any way to **rearrange** my Actions in *UFT*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag and drop the actions in the test pane. Double click the test name (highlighted in the screen shot). Then you'll see the flow of the actions, just drag them in the order you want.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

I also found one solution to it which is:
When we create a Test in *UFT* then at the directory structure level it makes a **Action0** folder[image].

In this *Action0* Folder there is a file named as **"SCRIPT"**. What you need to do is just open this *Script* in any editor and rearrange the Action's statements in the order we want them to run.

For Example:
RunAction "Action3", oneIteration
RunAction "Action1", oneIteration
RunAction "Action2", oneIteration

By doing this UFT will execute Action3 first then Action1 and lastly Action2.
The sole purpose of **Action0** is to rearrange the Action's Execution.